# after() inserting element, then getting it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-after

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does jQuery .after() not chain the new element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114266/why-does-jquery-after-not-chain-the-new-element)

This reference code:

```
$("#id").after(string);
```

Does a pretty good job inserting the element of the string where its need to.

How can I get a reference to newly inserted HTML element (string)?

Comment: Wouldn't `string` reference what you've just insterted?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm assuming the newly inserted one.

Comment: @DavidThomas: Not if it's not a jQuery object.

Comment: @Rocket, well, no; but that's why I was asking. Though I should, perhaps, have been more clear about the question? So: what is `string`, what is it that's expected/desired from this question?

Comment: Rocket is on the right track.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
var string = '<div id="some_HTML"><span>hello kitty</span></div>';

$jq_elem = $(string);  //if it's not a jQuery object, make it one

$("#id").after($jq_elem); //insert into DOM

$jq_elem.css('color', 'red'); //still available
​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8J757/)

Comment: +1 - so far you're the only one who recognizes that the string becomes an element if you pass it into the jquery constructor/selector

Answer (score 11):

Try using `insertAfter`:

```
var $str = $(string).insertAfter('#id');
```

This will work if `string` is HTML.